# Python script to process subtitles by jojolafrite not working

Tags: python

This script was posted on the interweb to insert 'silence lines' in a .srt subtitles file so that subtitles don't stay on too long, as indicated. 
I can't figure out how to pass the subtitle file name; always get:

> "type error: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NonType' and 'tuple'"

when I run with a file name after the module or

> "Please provide subtitle file to process"

from the code if I don't. Is the code faulty of am I making a stupid error? Cheers.

---

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys;

# Patching SRT files to make them readable on Samsung TVs
# It basically inserts blank subtitles when silence should occur.

seqNo=1

try:
    subs = open(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "Please provide subtitle file to process"
    sys.exit(1)

while True:
    srtSeqNo=subs.readline();
    try:
        begin,arrow,end=subs.readline().rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
    except:
        break
    srtText = subs.readline();
    again = subs.readline();
    while len(again.strip('\n\r')) > 0:
        srtText = srtText + again
        again = subs.readline()
    print "%d\n%s --> %s\n%s" % (seqNo, begin, end, srtText)

    seqNo = seqNo + 1
    print "%d\n%s --> %s\n%s\n" % (seqNo, end, end, "   ")
    seqNo = seqNo + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look after the `sys.argv`.

You must execute the script with the the full qualified path of your SRT file as an argument. Something like:

```
python script.py /home/user/folder/foo.srt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that."type error: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NonType' and 'tuple'"

Comment: I put everything in the same directory so: python subs.py C:/python34/test.srt but result is: %d
%s --> %s
%s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "subs.py", line 26, in <module>
   print ("%d\n%s --> %s\n%s)") % (serNo, begin, end, srtText)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NonType' and 'tuple'"

Answer (score 0):

The script is functioning properly. This worked for me:

```
python main.py torchwood.srt
```

Here, my `torchwood.srt` file was in the same directory where the `main.py` file was. You can use full path of the subtitle file if it's not in the same directory.

You must pass an existing `.srt` file with valid contents. If the file is not found or can not be opened, it will display `"Please provide subtitle file to process"`. So check file path and file permissions too.